# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException error while creating dialog box

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

I am trying to create a Dialog Box from an Non activity Class.

This is my Code

```
  public static void ShowDialogBox(final Context con, final Listener list) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
        dlgAlert.setMessage("TEXT");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("TEXT");
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("TEXT"),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
        dlgAlert.create().show(); // THIS LINE GIVES ME AN ERROR
    }
```

This is the error which I am getting

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:574)   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView
>   (WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>   at android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:298)   at
>   PACKAGE NAME AND CLASS
>   PACKAGE NAME AND CLASS   at
>   PACKAGE NAME AND CLASS
>   PACKAGE NAME AND CLASS  at
>   PACKAGE NAME AND CLASS.onBackPressed
>   (Class.java:95)   at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp
>   (Activity.java:2465)   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch
>   (KeyEvent.java:2646)   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent
>   (Activity.java:2716)   at
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent
>   (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent
>   (PhoneWindow.java:2280)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4038)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4000)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3562) 
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3615)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3581) 
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3698)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3589)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3755)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3562) 
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3615)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3581) 
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3589)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3562)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3615)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3581) 
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3731)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:3892)   at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run
>   (InputMethodManager.java:2208)   at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback
>   (InputMethodManager.java:1849)   at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent
>   (InputMethodManager.java:1840)   at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished
>   (InputMethodManager.java:2185)   at
>   android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished
>   (InputEventSender.java:141)   at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)   at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:143)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:122)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5254)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:902)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:697)

Here is the scenario of the user

**Activity A -->Opens Activity B-->User presses Back button in Activity B--> On Back button pressed a listener is sent to Activity A --> And then the Dialog Box shown is called.**

Comment: More information on the "Non activity Class" would be helpful.

Comment: @Barns Thanks. It is More of an Utility class which I have created to optimize the repetition of the Code. Also the `ShowDialogBox` method is called from an Activity Class. It is like Activity Class calls `ShowDialogBox` shows an Dialog box. This is an Class which has various other methods such as Opening an activity, Initalizing something etc etc. Please let me know if further info is needed.

Comment: It is probably just an typo you made while simplifying your code for your post, but you have this`dlgAlert.setMessage("TEXT);` with an open quotation on `"TEXT` in stead of `"TEXT"` unless `TEXT` is a variable and should be just `TEXT` ???

Comment: Try your luck with a `DialogFragment`. I have posted an example below.

Comment: @Barns Thanks. Yes you are right this is my mistake in this post. OK, will try that, but any idea why this error? I have edited the question to give you a better scenario of the situation.

Comment: :: Take a look at my second answer. It provides a bit more info about the error you get. It also provides a "quick fix"  to your issue. I kept my first answer  with the `DialogFragmen` because it is the preferred way to " outsource"  the `AlertDialog` and other dialogs.

Comment: @Barns Thanks have accepted you second Answer as it suits me more. But will surely try Dialog Fragment also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having with the attempt to build your `AlertDialog` in a separate class is you are passing the `AlertDialog` the `Context` of your `Activity`. You get the error because the `AlertDialog` requires the `WindowManager` from the `Activity` which has the layout--not the `Context`. This is because `Activit` extends `Context`... not the other way around.

In order to make your code work you need to provide the `AlertDialog.Builder` access to the `Activity`. So change your code to something like this:

```
public class TestDialog {

    private static final String TAG = TestDialog.class.getSimpleName();

    Activity mActivity;

    public TestDialog(Activity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
    }


    public void showDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        b.setTitle("Title");
        b.setMessage("message");
        b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.e(TAG, "showDialog : onClick");
            }
        });
        b.create().show();
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `AlertDialog` from an `Activity` lets say in this case `MainActivity` like this:

```
TestDialog testDialog = new TestDialog(MainActivity.this);
testDialog.showDialog();
```

I have not tried this from a `Fragment`, so I do not know whether this works from a `Fragment` or whether you will continue to have issues with certain devices. For those reasons, I (and Google!) still strongly suggest that you use the `DialogFragment` instead, because is has been especially designed for this scenario. Take a look at the Google Docs.:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer using `DialogFragment` instead of what you attempted in order to cut down on repetition. Here is an example of a `DialogFragment` with a custom layout which I have called `R.layout.fragment_alert_dialog`:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    private String title;
    private String message;
    boolean endSuccess = false;

    private AlertFinishedDialogListener mListener;

    public AlertDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static AlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialogFragment fragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
            message = getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveIntsanceState){

        final Context context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert_dialog, null, false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        final TextView messView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messView.setText(message);

        builder.setView(rootView)
//                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        endSuccess = true;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (AlertFinishedDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onAlertFinishedDialog();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            if(mListener == null) mListener = (AlertFinishedDialogListener) context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface AlertFinishedDialogListener {
        void onAlertFinishedDialog();
    }
}
```

It incorporates a `Listener` just in case you need to be notified when the `DialogFragment` is completed.

First you need to implement the callback:
        `implements AlertDialogFragment.AlertFinishedDialogListener{`

In order to call the `AlertDialogFragment` you do this from your `Activity` (also `Fragment` if necessary).

```
private void startAlertDialogFragment(String title, String mess){
    AlertDialogFragment alert = AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(title, mess);
    alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "alertDialogFragment132");
}

@Override
public void onAlertFinishedDialog() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onAlertFinishedDialog");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Problem**

**You can show dialogs from activity context only.** except [TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT) or [TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY), which is not recommended if your app does not show emergency notifications to user.

> **Solution**

If you have activity context available then you can show dialog from any class like `service`, `broadcast receiver`, or even any class you imagine.

Here is my workaround that can show dialog from any class like i said.

> Here is a snippet what i do to show dialog from any class. (**Could it
>   be more simpler!**)

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class SampleClass {
    void anyMethod() {
        Dialog dialog = ApplicationContext.getInstance().showDialog("title", "yourMessage", "Cancel", "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO: handle button 1 clicked 
            }
        }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO: handle button 2 clicked
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now you will implement to make this work.

**1. make application class which you will register in android manifest application tag**

```
  <application
    android:name=".ApplicationContext"
    ...
    >
      ...
  </application>
```

**2. In this application class you will hold live activity object. that will further useful for showing dialog.**

*ApplicationContext.java*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class ApplicationContext extends Application {
    private static ApplicationContext mInstance;
    private Activity liveActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        mInstance = null;
    }

    public static synchronized ApplicationContext getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public Activity getLiveActivity() {
        return liveActivity;
    }

    public void setLiveActivity(Activity liveActivity) {
        this.liveActivity = liveActivity;
    }

    /*
     * Show Dialog with Title, Message, Button1, Button2 with Button1 and Button2 Listener
     */
    public AlertDialog showDialog(String title, String msg,
                                  String btn1, String btn2,
                                  DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener1,
                                  DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener2) {
        if (liveActivity == null) return null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(liveActivity)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(btn1, listener1);
        if (btn2 != null)
            builder.setNegativeButton(btn2, listener2);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        return alert;
    }
}
```

*Just one more step*

**3. You will extend all your activity by this base activity class (You can edit your base activity if you already have one.)**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ApplicationContext.getInstance().setLiveActivity(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ApplicationContext.getInstance().setLiveActivity(null);
    }
}
```

**Here you go !!!**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the Context is of an Activity. I mean that I am making the method accept a context which is of an Activity but still I am getting this error only on some mobiles mostly Samsung. Will surely try you solution also.